# Error in compiling in Java: no suitable constructor found for Turtle(no arguments)

Tags: java

When I compile this error shows up, I'm not sure what could be wrong.

This is the error that comes up when I compile:

```
Error: no suitable constructor found for Turtle(no arguments)
     constructor Turtle.Turtle(int,int,Picture) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    constructor Turtle.Turtle(int,int,ModelDisplay) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    constructor Turtle.Turtle(ModelDisplay) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    constructor Turtle.Turtle(Picture) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
```

This is the code I wrote:

```
public class CreateShapes extends Turtle

{

    {
        //Put all your commands to call drawShape 4 times on 4 different turtle objects

      World world1 = new World();
      Turtle turtle1 = new Turtle(50,50,world1);
      turtle1.drawShape(100);
      Turtle turtle2 = new Turtle(100, 100,world1);
      turtle1.drawShape(200);
      Turtle turtle3 = new Turtle(200,200,world1);
      turtle1.drawShape(300);
      Turtle turtle4 = new Turtle(300,300, world1);
      turtle1.drawShape(400);

    }
}
```

Comment: What does the error tell you? It says you don't have a constructor that accepts no args. Could it be the hidden code you didnt show us where you create a CreateShapes instance like new CreateShapes()?

Comment: What exact line of code is it complaining about? And show us the Turtle class

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `Turtle` has four different constructors: one with two `int`s and a `Picture` instance, one with two `int`s and a `ModelDisplay` instance, one with a `ModelDisplay` instance, and one with a `Picture` instance passed as an argument.

You are attempting to initiate `Turtle`s with two `int`s and a `World` instance.

Unless `World` is a subclass of `ModelDisplay` or `Picture`, this won't work. Make sure to provide the correct third argument.